# How to create a checkbox around the entire div?

Tags: html, jsp, checkbox

I am using jsp to create a webpage that would allow people to select multiple products by clicking on them (through a checkbox on top of them). The description, image etc etc is displayed through a database as a list onto the screen, each product in a separate div. My question is, how do i get to create a border around each of the divs and a checkbox somewhere along that border for each div (preferably a corner). my code snippet (i am using a bean for handling all connections etc):

```
 <div id="div1">   
    <%
        Set rs = Etn.execute("select * from products");
        while(rs.next()){
            %><div><%
        out.write(rs.value("id")+" ");
        out.write (rs.value("image_name")+"<br>");
        out.write(rs.value("image_actual_name")+" ");
        out.write(rs.value("product_type")+"<br><br>");
        %></div><%
        }

    %>    


 </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put your checkbox hidden and set your div as labels. When a label is checked, put some border on the connected label